# MS Access app shows "Enter parameter value" only on some machines

Tags: vba, ms-access

In an MS Access app I have a main form that has some buttons, one of which is a "Calendar" button.

When this button is clicked, a form that implements some kind of calendar should open.

The problem is that on some clean machines where I deployed this, instead of the calendar opening, an **Enter parameter value** dialog opens. On 3 other older instances it works without this problem.

On that form there is an unbound control that has default value `=Now()`

Office version 2013.

Where and how can I look for differences between these machines?

I can add code snippets or print screens to this question if you let me know what part exactly.

**UPDATE:**

[image: First field]

[image: Second field]

The code in the open form altough before this get's executed the "Enter parameter value" dialog shows.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim PrstAnz As Integer

On Error GoTo Form_Open_EH

If DCount("[prst]", "FLMT_AKTPRST") > 1 Then
    'Es stehen mehrere Prüfstände zur Auswahl
    Me.prst.Visible = True
    Me.prst.RowSource = "FLMT_AKTPRST"
End If

Me![prst] = DLookup("[prst]", "FLMT_AKTPRST")

Me![ABeginn] = Date
InitPrst Me![ABeginn]

Exit Sub
```

[image: Dialog snipp]

All machines are Windows 7 x64 with Office 2013.

Comment: Is this a date picker control?  Are the machines it doesn't work on 64 bit?

Comment: Check the selected libraries in the VBA editor. Any tagged as MISSING?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't get the "Enter the Parameter Value" just because it's on a different machine. You mention older instances - can you clarify if those are running a previous version of Access? If so, what version? Furthermore, what parameter does the dialog ask for?

Comment: What is the Record Source of the form representing the calendar?

Comment: @Comintern I'm not sure but I think so since a date picker show up at runtime when I click on the icon near that field.

Comment: @June7 Checked, none MISSING.

Comment: @this The machines are exactly the same Win7 x64, Office 2013. I will compare the entire list of KB's don't know else what to do for now. You can see the snips in the update post.

Comment: @Lee Mac The form itself does not have a Record Source.

Comment: There are still few more questions: The screenshot shows the form from where the calendar should be opened, right? It's not the calendar itself? Then you post a snippet of form's Open code - but is that the calendar form's Open code? We are missing the `DoCmd.OpenForm` or its equivalent which may illustrate how you are opening the calendar and thus why you're getting the parameter value dialog.

Comment: @this The snip shows the calendar form itself. The command is on a button click event on another main form and looks like this: DoCmd.OpenForm "FLMF_TERMINE_PRST" .

Comment: Am I to understand that when you open the form `FLMF_TERMINE_PRST`, you get a parameter value dialog for `Formulare!FLMF_TERMINE_PRST!ABeginn`? If that is the case, then my next question would be if you have any expression `Formulare!FLMF_TERMINE_PRST!ABeginn` anywhere on your calendar form.

Comment: @this Yes, you understand correctly. There are expressions containing this "Me![ABeginn]"  in some places, as you can see in code in original post for e.g. "Me![ABeginn] = Date"

Comment: Though that wasn't the question, note that you really have no reason to use the bang notations with controls on a form. In fact, it ends up hiding any potential compiler errors. That said, based on the information you've given, I am not inclined to think this is found in VBA code but rather an expression stored in one of various properties in the controls or the form itself that references to itself. I would review them all and replace them. One more thing to be 100% sure - is there a difference in the languages used among the Office?

Comment: @this There are no differences in Region or Language settings, in fact as I mentioned previously there are no differences that I know of between machines. Anyway if there is some difference between the machines it's a very subtle one and I don't know were to start to find it. I give up.

Comment: Agree with @this, inclined to think there is a reference to Formulare!FLMF_TERMINE_PRST!ABeginn somewhere in form design that doesn't agree with new machines. Why? No idea. Had a similar occurrence where a new machine refused to execute a procedure, no error, just would not run. Finally switched machines for this user and no more issue.

Comment: If your tables are on a DB server, like Oracle, the driver can make a difference. Oracle driver does not behave like ms driver for Oracle, for instance

Answer (score 0):

It's was about OS culture settings.